# How to send my user back to my first app screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send my user back tho my first screen, the `home` widget passed as parameter to the `MaterialApp`, but I am very deep into my navigation routes.

```
class Myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyFirstPage(), // <-- I want go on back here
    );
  }
}
```

There is an easy way of doing it with Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName));
```

The `home` widget is for the default route of the app Navigator.defaultRouteName, which is `/`.